# Windows of data with possibility to decide if store

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

This is a very general question.

I have a series of data with a quantity (y) versus time (x). It is a very long series and the data are sometimes pretty noisy, some times better.

I would like to write a python code that allows me to take a look at these data with a given x-range per time (just a snapshot, so to say), and then allow me to decide if I want to "store" the sequence or not. Then pass to the next sequence and do the same, and so on. So at the end I will have a stacked amount of sequences that I can analyze separately.

I need some suggestions about the graphical part: I don't have a clue of which modules I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) is probably one of the best options for the graphical part. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()

# make some data of some size
nblocks = 10
block_size = 1000
size = block_size*nblocks
data = np.random.normal(0.,1.,size=size)

# create a matplotlib figure with some plotting axes
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# display the figure
plt.show()

# storage for blocks to keep
kept_blocks = []

for block in data.reshape(nblocks,block_size):
    #plot the block
    ax.plot(block)

    #force matplotlib to rerender
    plt.draw()

    # ask user for some input
    answer = raw_input("Keep block? [Y/n]")
    if answer.lower() != "n":
        kept_blocks.append(block)

    #clear the plotting axes
    ax.cla()

# turn the kept blocks into a 2D array
kept_blocks = np.vstack(kept_blocks)

#or a 1D array
#kept_blocks = np.hstack(kept_blocks)
```

Matplotlib is well supported and is the *de facto* plotting standard in python.

Comment: Thanks! Do you also have any tip on how to "reshape" the data according to some limit values? The x-axis is time, the data are periodic, so I want to show different sets for consequential periods.

Comment: So I do stuff like this quite often with the data I use, but I tend to phase bin data with different periods (i.e. fold the data like a piece of paper modulo the desired periodicity). Are the period(s) in the data an integer or fractional number of samples?

Comment: I am using phase indeed. I think I managed it, somehow, but I would like to know your opinion nonetheless. The last sentence I do not understand. I have time versus flux, this flux has a periodicity, and I show one period-range (in phase) each "window".

Comment: Out of interest, what kind of data is it, supernova lightcurves, pulsars, AGN variability? The last sentence means does Period = N*sampling interval where N is an integer.

Comment: Pulsar. I am checking out the orbital profile. What do you mean by sampling interval?

Comment: For playing with pulsar data in any of the standard formats ".fil", ".dat" or ".tim" I'll plug this: https://github.com/ewanbarr/sigpyproc which I wrote. Sampling interval is the length of a single time sample. Alternatively it is 1/(sampling rate).

Comment: I have a fits file (but ofc I can extract a .dat). Where can I read what your scripts are useful to?
By sampling interval do you mean the time binning/time resolution?

Comment: Sampling interval = time resolution, yes. The sigpyproc package is really just an interface for manual manipulation of pulsar data. There aren't many example scripts, but if you do `from sigpyproc.Readers import readDat` you can read a dat file with `dat = readDat(<name of dat file>,<name of inf file>)`. The `TimeSeries` object returned by that function has a `fold` method that you can play with.

Comment: The time binning is 6 hours. what is `inf` file? Is there a document where I can read all these features instead of asking you one by one? :)

Comment: There is some documentation, but it is a bit out of date now (http://www3.mpifr-bonn.mpg.de/staff/ebarr/sigpyproc/Tutorial.html). It is probably a good place to start. The `inf` files are metadata files for PRESTO format data.

Comment: Thanks! Never worked with PRESTO data, basically only fits and similar. However, I usually use FTOOLS to play with these data, they also have FT and EFOLDING routines, plus many others.

Comment: No worries, I was coming at this from a radio perspective not a gamma-ray one. Good luck with the analysis.